# Correct way of adding new columns/headers to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need to add new columns to a dataframe. Every column has a header and a value across all the rows (the value is the same for all the columns).

Right now im doing something like this:

```
array_of_new_headers = [...]
for column in array_of_new_headers:
   df[column] = 0
```

As a result I'm getting this message:

> PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many
> times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead.  To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`

It tells me to use concat, but, I don't need to concatenate two dataframes really, should I use concat for better performance and better code? To me it doesn't really make sense unless I think of the arrays as also dataframes maybe.

Comment: Maybe you can create a new df and concetrate em then?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an unpacked dictionary with keys as column names, and values as value for the columns to `pandas.DataFrame.assign` :

```py
>>> array_of_new_headers = [...]
>>> df.assign(**{c:0 for c in array_of_new_headers})
```

*But the operation is immutable, so make sure to assign it back to the required variable.*

Answer (score 0):

> should I use concat for better performance

Beware so-called *premature optimization*, if your code does work rapidly enough for your needs then you might end simply wasting your time on trying to make it faster.